# how this while(true) is working

Tags: java, while-loop

```
package interf;

public class NumberPrinter {

  public interface Printer {
    public void print (int idx);
  }

  public static void print (Printer p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        p.print(i);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
      System.out.println("hi-1");

      print(new Printer() {

        @Override
        public void print(int idx) {
          while(true){
              System.out.println(idx);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

why it only printing 0 0  0
why it is not printing System.out.println("hi-1");

Comment: Fix the terrible indentation first.

Comment: When asking for help, please show the courtesy of formatting your code readably. I don't just mean your failing to mark it as code, but the indentation of the code itself. You can do whatever you like when only working on it yourself, but when asking for help, change it to something readable, consistent, and in keeping with any of the several standard schemes. Miky Dinescu has done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: What is the output you are getting ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi: It's at the bottom: "it only printing 0 0 0"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is not true it is printing hi-1 but it goes so fast he doesn't see it. If he would actually debug instead of posting it here for us to debug it he would have seen it first.

Comment: IMHO, it prints `"hi-1"` then it prints `0 0 0 ` in an infinite loop.

Comment: He changed the capital when he was indenting, it did compile before. And, it does print hi-1. But it only does it once before entering an infinite loop.

Comment: I think your hi-1 just gets hidden by all the 0 lines and you don't see it

Comment: Before blindly posting SO question please atleast once in a while go through this [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just copy and pasted it into eclipse and it is running for me.

Comment: @CodeCamper: Turns out the person who formatted the code for the OP accidentally introduced the error in the code I picked up on (Richard has now fixed it), which just happens to have been on the relevant line. So my theory (that they were running a previous `.class` file, having missed the compilation error) fit the facts, but the facts were wrong. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The code (when fixed to make `system` `System`) prints "hi-1" then lots of 0's (forever), because your inner print method has a `while(true)` loop in it.

The outer `while(true)` loop is never executed more than once because your code gets "stuck" in this inner loop, so you never see "hi-1" more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the second while loop and capitalize the first letter of `system.out.println` and you'll get an infinite loop of:

```
hi-1
0
1
2
3
hi-1
0
1
2
3
...
```

---

```
package interf;

public class NumberPrinter {

  public interface Printer {
    public void print (int idx);
  }

  public static void print (Printer p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        p.print(i);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
      System.out.println("hi-1");

      print(new Printer() {

        @Override
        public void print(int idx) {
          //while(true){
              System.out.println(idx);
          //}
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println("hi-1"); i do not see this line printing in my eclipse console, only zeros are printing. i just want know why hi-1 is not showing, rest of code i do understand. i just what see 2 while(true) working in the original code shown first.